# Issue with setting up custom analyzer wiith failed to parse mapping error

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Issue with setting up custom analyzer with the following:
"phoneNumber" : {

"type": "keyword",

"fields" : {

"numvalue" : {

"type":"long",

"analyzer": "phone_analyzer"

}}}

"phone_analyzer" : {

"tokenizer":"standard",

"char_filter": ["phone_number']}

"char_filter" :{

"phone_number": {

"type":"pattern_replace",

"pattern": "[^0-9]",

"replacement":""

}}

So basically my intention is to have the "raw value" to still be used as keyword while I created a new field called numvalue where it is long and using a custom analyzer with a chat_filter that replaces all non-digit values with "" (no space). So if things work out, my front end will retrieve the raw value - with - or + or whatever and my backend search will use the "numvalue" in the range search.

When i ran it i did get "mapper_parsing_exception" "failed to parse mapping [_doc] unknown parameter [analyzer] on mapper [numvalue] of type [long] status 400.

There are other analyzers around too. Do you have any idea why? I am using 7.* for Elastic search b

Comment: Please use the code indentation tools to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Doc:

> Each field has a field data type, or field type. This type indicates
> the kind of data the field contains, such as strings or boolean
> values, and its intended use. For example, you can index strings to
> both text and keyword fields. However, text field values are analyzed
> for full-text search while keyword strings are left as-is for
> filtering and sorting.

Change type long to Text. Only Text type works with analyzer.

Query

```
GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "phoneNumber.numvalue": {
        "gte": 55343457
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "phone_number": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[^0-9]",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "phone_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "phone_number"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "phoneNumber": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "numvalue": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "phone_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST idx_test/_doc
{
  "phoneNumber":"+553434-56"
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I thought long is a field type? So the phone number is keyword and the supplemental field I want it to be a number so I can later find the ranges of. If I make it into text then how would I do that search later.

Comment: I think is possible to use: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-text-and-keyword

Comment: I think the other problem is removing non numerics as well. I am not seeing the fields I added on my results.